# RowDefinitions/ColumnDefinition not working on WindowsPhone but works fine on WindowsPhone emulator

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.winphone

When I try to run the app on windows emulator it runs fine but when I try to run on a windows phone it gives the following error

```
Object of type 'Xamarin.Forms.ColumnDefinition' cannot be converted to type 'Xamarin.Forms.View'
```

I am getting this error at the following lines

```
<Grid.ColumnDefinitions>


</Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
```